# Working with tuples in Haskell

Tags: haskell

So i have a list of tuples like this one xs = [("a","b"),("a","c"),("b","d")], and i want to make a function that receives this list of numbers and an element 'a', and returns what it's in the second positions of the tuples, where that 'a' is the first element. 
  In the example above, if the function received the list xs and the letter 'a' it should return:
["b","c"]

Answer (score 6):

```
lookupAll :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> [b]
lookupAll x pairs = [b | (a, b) <- pairs, a == x]
```

Comment: Or the mappy way, `lookupAll = map snd .: filter . (. fst) . (==)`

Comment: Fair enough, I just thought it a worth while thought that wasn't quite an answer

Comment: I do appreciate the contribution.  I was just commenting because points-free is often shorter and clearer, and in this case it's not.

Comment: I tend to avoid it whenever I'm composing operators and `(. f)`s. I cannot read those fluently at all...